# How can I properly bind an enum within a dropdown menu in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, enums

In a dropdown menu, I've used an Enum data structure (*Typescript*) to store my values. However it seems that the data binding to the object's category field doesn't take place properly and nothing is selected by default. Is there any better solution?

```
export enum CategoryEnum {
      EXAMPLECAT1 = 1,
      EXAMPLECAT2 = 2,
      EXAMPLECAT3 = 3,
      EXAMPLECAT4 = 4
    }

@Component({
  selector: 'category',
  template: `
    <label for="appCategory">Example Category: </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleCategory" required 
            (change)="parseValue($event.target.value)"
            (ngModelChange)="changeSelectedType($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let category of categoryTypes"
              [value]="category">{{category.type}}</option>
    </select>
  `
})

export class CategoryComponent {

  private selectedCategoryType: CategoryEnum
  private categoryTypes;

  constructor(){
    this.categoryTypes = CategoryMapping
  }

  parseValue(value : string) {
    this.selectedCategoryType = AppCategoryEnum[value];
  }

  //Logging: Change Selected Product type callback
  private changeSelectedType(event: any) {
    console.log(event); //object, depends on ngValue
    console.log(this.selectedCategoryType); //object, depends on ngValue
  }
}
```

Mapping the enum data type to labels:

```
export const CategoryMapping = [
  { value: ExampleCategoryEnum.EXAMPLECAT1, type: 'Example 1' },
  { value: ExampleCategoryEnum.EXAMPLECAT2, type: 'Example 2'},
  { value: ExampleCategoryEnum.EXAMPLECAT3, type: 'Example 3'},
  { value: ExampleCategoryEnum.EXAMPLECAT4, type: 'Example 4'}
];
```

Comment: You have to use `[ngValue]` for options when you want to send non-primitive types (in your case, objects)

Comment: And to select a value as default, you have to set your `ngModel` (which you lack on your select) to the default value you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

We can simplify the bind with `ngModel`, I have create another property to bind with select element and get property to get the vaLue as `CategoryEnum`

*compoenent*

```
  // I have change this to public just for demo
  public get selectedCategoryType():CategoryEnum {
    return this.selectedValue ? this.selectedValue.value: null; 
  }
  private categoryTypes;

  public selectedValue:any;

  constructor() {
    this.categoryTypes = CategoryMapping;
    this.selectedValue = this.categoryTypes[2]; // set default value 
  }
```

*template*

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleCategory" required  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" >
      <option></option>
      <option *ngFor="let category of categoryTypes"
              [ngValue]="category">{{category.type}}</option>
    </select>
<br>

selectedCategoryType :  {{selectedCategoryType | json}}
```

> You have to use [ngValue] for options when you want to send non-primitive types (in your case, objects) as @trichetriche said

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fsxvpz)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, set

```
<select ... [value]="1">
```

where `1` is example default category enum value.

And use `category.value` instead whole object `category` as option value

```
<option ... [value]="category.value" >
```

and update your .ts file to handle that change.

Comment: She is using objects as values, not numbers